stagnant Orange box keep showing on my pc
I am new to Ubuntu. I keep getting an orange box showing on my Ubuntu 24.04. It usually occurs when I am trying to split screens. The orange box is usually stagnant. It temporarily goes when I lock and open my PC or when I change the position of my split screen. Hoping I could find a more permanent fix. Here are the images:



This question is similar to: What is this orange thing taking up half of my screen?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Currently, the Ubuntu Tiling Assistant has a bug, that sometimes makes  these boxes staying on screen after a "tiling" operation is done. In some extreme cases, this bug may crash your GNOME session and result in loss of your work. On the previous version (23.10) of Ubuntu it did not have such a problem.
Please, go to Extensions (gnome-extensions-app), find Ubuntu Tiling Assistant (at the bottom) and disable it. You can try to modify some of its options and see if the problem goes away. Feel free to share your experiences here.
You can go to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-shell-extension-tiling-assistant/+bug/2063970 and add yourself as "This bug affects me".

Hey Fedkad, Thank you very much. This fixed the issue for me.  I upvoted your answer but I guess it won't show till I have 15 reputation.

@Tosin You can still Accept this answer. You also now have enough reputation to vote. I encourage you to do both!


For the GUI right-click on the desktop.
Choose Display Settings.
On the left-side menu scroll down to Ubuntu Desktop.
On the right side scroll down and find Enhanced Tiling and disable it.

Ubuntu Desktop settings:

